# Two way data binding nested Form state to localStorage in React

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, local-storage, state

I'm creating a form builder for users to create questions. Each question can have an infinite number of sub-questions and I want to save the data to localStorage.

What would be the best approach to dynamically update localStorage based on the state of each question/sub-question in the form since localStorage stores JSON? Is there a way to take Reacts one-way data flow principle and have its state run in parallel with local storage?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a state variable in your form component at the container level and call localStorage.set('MY_QUESTIONS', questionsObj) whenever there is an update to the form so that the localStorage object is synced with the state variable.

For example, you can call it in the callback of every state change:

```
handleQuestionsUpdate() {
    this.setState({
      formQuestions: newQuestions
    }, () => {
      localStorage.setItem('MY_QUESTIONS', this.state.formQuestions)
    });
}
```

Comment: I ended up using lodash's _.set method on the app layer and passing each form input a path key that maps to it's position in the tree